# Python print two outcomes on same lines over and over

Tags: python

Running a program in cmd; the print function

```
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
    page = requests.get(url)
    print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),

if text2search in page.text:
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
    (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
    (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
    writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
```

Which returns: **Scraping URL 1 of 400**

Over and over till count ends.

What i'm trying to learn today, is printing 2 outcomes on 2 separate lines, over and over till loop ends.

Example:

Scraping URL **1** of 400 Where bold character is only thing changing

Then if the scraper finds a result in the list;

Adding Result **1** to CSV Where bold character is only thing changing

So far i have tried a few print commands, but it either overwrites the entire sentence on the same line;

```
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),

     if text2search in page.text:
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
        (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
       (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
       writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
       print '\r' 'URL_FOUND' + str(index+1) + 'adding to CSV',
```

If i try to link to two print functions to an else argument, it will only print the first statement and the second is not acknowledged.

```
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),
else:
        if text2search in page.text:
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
        (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
        (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
        writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
        print '\n' 'title'
```

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for printing two outcomes on 2 lines.

Full code below if required:

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
from lxml import html

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Python27\Projects\REA_SCRAPER\\REA.xlsx", sheetname="REA")
dnc = df['Property']
dnc_list = list(dnc)
url_base = "https://www.realestate.com.au/property/"
URL_LIST = []

for nd in dnc_list:
    nd = nd.strip()
    nd = nd.lower()
    nd = nd.replace(" ", "-")
    URL_LIST.append(url_base + nd)

text2search = '''RECENTLY SOLD'''

with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),

        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
            (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
            writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have recommended [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html), but you're on Windows and just writing what appears to be a small script; reason enough to not go down that rabbit hole.

The reason you are seeing your lines overwrite each other is because you are printing carriage returns `\r`, which moves the cursor to the start of the line. Any text written thereafter will overwrite previous printed text.

I found [this](https://github.com/Yinzo/reprint) with a quick Google, which may be of interest to you.